# Revover original email from Sendmail log

Tags: sendmail, log-files

I have a website the contact form has been failing silently for two weeks (Wordpress + Contact form 7).

Apparently updating to Contact Form 7 made the assigned email to fail some_email@telefonica.net, I also tested with some_email@me.com and it also failed until I tried with gmail and it finally worked.

Apparently @telefonica.net and @me.com domains are not working with this version of the plugin, but I have to investigate the cause.

I found the logs of the lost emails, **but I would like to know If I can recover the sender or the content of the original messages.**

```
May 24 23:41:11 localhost sendmail[27653]: s4P3fBc3027653: from=www-data, size=3250, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<381d75ab52e7f3667ed1eb0f9e70bd51@www.some_web.com>, relay=www-data@localhost
May 24 23:41:11 localhost sm-mta[27655]: s4P3fBdA027655: from=<www-data@li306-103.members.linode.com>, size=3359, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<381d75ab52e7f3667ed1eb0f9e70bd51@www.some_web.com>, proto=ESMTP, daemon=MTA-v4, relay=localhost.localdomain [127.0.0.1]
May 24 23:41:11 localhost sendmail[27653]: s4P3fBc3027653: to=some_email@telefonica.net, ctladdr=www-data (33/33), delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=33250, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (s4P3fBdA027655 Message accepted for delivery)
May 24 23:41:12 localhost sm-mta[27657]: s4P3fBdA027655: to=<some_email@telefonica.net>, ctladdr=<www-data@li306-103.members.linode.com> (33/33), delay=00:00:01, xdelay=00:00:01, mailer=esmtp, pri=123359, relay=tnetmx.telefonica.net. [86.109.99.69], dsn=5.0.0, stat=Service unavailable
May 24 23:41:12 localhost sm-mta[27657]: s4P3fBdA027655: s4P3fCdA027657: DSN: Service unavailable
May 24 23:41:12 localhost sm-mta[27657]: s4P3fCdA027657: to=<www-data@li306-103.members.linode.com>, delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=local, pri=30000, dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's not in the log files and the mails have been sent, they will be deleted from the queues and are lost.

Answer (score 0):

You may recover the envelope sender, envelope recipients and message size from sendmail's log files.

Recovery of message content would require **earlier** installation features e.g. archiving milter.